# Invalid characters passed for attempted conversion while making pdf

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

When i am creating PDF it is showing below error in laravel

Invalid characters passed for attempted conversion, these have been ignored

```
use Barryvdh\DomPDF\PDF as PDF;
```

My Controller

```
public function pdf_invoice($id)
{
    $order = Order::findOrFail($id);        
    $pdf = \PDF::loadView('admin.order.print', compact('order'));  
    return $pdf->download($order->order_number.'.pdf');              
}
```

Error Showing in

```
dompdf\dompdf\lib\Cpdf.php
```

Error Showing in below line of Code

```
  if ($c != hexdec($n)) 
 {$data['codeToName'][$c] = $n;}
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: Please analyze the values in `$order`, usually the libraries dont have errors, they show the errors due to data passed to them, so the first this is you should check data

Comment: I already checked it, even i passed hard coded "hello" in in the view it's showing same error

Comment: Your view itself could contain characters the PDF generator considers invalid.

Comment: if i remove all things from view it will make empty pdf with same view

Comment: @Brio, this means you should look for the issue in your view file

Comment: i have resolved issue removing if condition if ($c != hexdec($n)) 
 {$data['codeToName'][$c] = $n;} now it's working